# "Scheduling update, current focus is $_primaryFocus, next focus will be $_markedForFocus" when running Flutter app on Web

Tags: flutter

I am having the this error "Scheduling update, current focus is $_primaryFocus, next focus will be $_markedForFocus" when I run my Flutter app on web, but when I run it on mobile/desktop, it runs just fine. What could it be? I am not using any kind of focus() instance or anything like it. It throws this error right when I try to click on one of the buttons of the home screen:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: const MyDrawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Tela inicial"),
          actions: const [
            IconSwitchTheme(),
          ],
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 400
                  ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 700
                      ? 40.0
                      : 24.0
                  : 19.0),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height < 700
                      ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15
                      : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/labsec-logo.png"),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Desafio App",
                    style: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height < 700
                        ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge
                        : Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .bodyLarge!
                            .copyWith(fontSize: 50.0),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                Expanded(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 700
                        ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.45
                        : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                    child: GridView.count(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 15.0,
                      children: [
                        CustomButton(
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                              .pushNamed("/bluetooth-devices"),
                          child: const HomeScreenButtonChild(
                            icon: Icons.bluetooth,
                            text: "Dispositivos LBE",
                          ),
                        ),
                        CustomButton(
                          onPressed: () =>
                              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/rsa-keys'),
                          child: const HomeScreenButtonChild(
                            icon: Icons.key,
                            text: "Gerar chaves RSA",
                          ),
                        ),
                        CustomButton(
                          onPressed: () =>
                              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/sign-list'),
                          child: const HomeScreenButtonChild(
                            icon: Icons.edit_note,
                            text: "Assinar lista",
                          ),
                        ),
                        CustomButton(
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                              .pushNamed('/verify-signature'),
                          child: const HomeScreenButtonChild(
                            icon: Icons.search,
                            text: "Verificar assinatura",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomButton({
    super.key,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.child,
    this.style,
    this.spinner,
  });

  final VoidCallback? onPressed;
  final ButtonStyle? style;
  final bool? spinner;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      style: style,
      child: spinner != null ? const CircularProgressIndicator() : child,
    );
  }
}
```

```
class HomeScreenButtonChild extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreenButtonChild({
    super.key,
    required this.icon,
    required this.text,
  });

  final IconData icon;
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Icon(icon,
                  size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 700
                      ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 1000
                          ? 120.0
                          : 80.0
                      : 40.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Text(
                  text,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 700
                          ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 1000
                              ? 40.0
                              : 20.0
                          : 16.0),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDrawer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeMode themeMode = context.watch<ThemeProvider>().themeMode;

    return Drawer(
      backgroundColor: themeMode == ThemeMode.light
          ? Colors.white
          : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Center(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "CONFIGURAÇÕES",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                          color: themeMode == ThemeMode.light
                              ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary
                              : Colors.white,
                        ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                    iconSize: 30,
                    color: themeMode == ThemeMode.light
                        ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary
                        : Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // const Divider(),
          ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(
              Icons.delete,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            title: Text(
              "Deletar todos os dados",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              context.read<BluetoothDevicesProvider>().clearProvider();
              context.read<RSAKeysProvider>().clearProvider();
              context.read<SignatureProvider>().clearProvider();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.7.3 on channel stable at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.7.3/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 9944297138 (2 weeks ago), 2023-02-08 15:46:04 -0800
    • Engine revision 248290d6d5
    • Dart version 2.19.2
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/enrico/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.58.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 110.0.5481.100

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```